# Arranging Firefox's UI bars with -moz-box-ordinal-group

Tags: firefox, css, user-interface, toolbar

I updated my FF to 65.0 (64-Bit) on Windows 7 today and now the following settings in my `userChrome.css` aren't considered any longer:

```
/* Tab bar below Navigation & Bookmarks Toolbars */
#nav-bar { /* main toolbar */
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1 !important;
    border-top-width: 0 !important;
    }
#PersonalToolbar { /* bookmarks toolbar */
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2 !important;
    border-top-width: 0 !important;
    }
#TabsToolbar { /* tab bar */
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3 !important;
    border-top-width: 0 !important;
    }
```

I.e. instead of:

- menu bar
- main toolbar
- bookmarks toolbar
- tab bar

it's:

- menu bar
- tab bar   ← this is not as intended
- main toolbar
- bookmarks toolbar

How to change the settings to the intended (and previous) behavour?

Comment: `moz-box-ordinal-group` is deprecated and on the way out : [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-ordinal-group).

Answer (score 1):

All the `-moz-*` CSS additions are non-standard and belong to the time when CSS
was just starting and was lacking many options. While waiting for the standard
to evolve, Mozilla has added these CSS items as a stop-gap measure.

The Mozilla 
[-moz-box-ordinal-group documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-ordinal-group)
contains this:

> **Warning**: This is a property of the original CSS Flexible Box Layout Module draft, and has been replaced in newer drafts.
>
> See
>   [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
>   for more information on what you should be using instead of this property.

The general
[Mozilla CSS extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Mozilla_Extensions)
also has this:

> Mozilla applications such as Firefox support a number of special
>   Mozilla extensions to CSS, including properties, values,
>   pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes, at-rules, and media queries. These
>   extensions are prefixed with -moz-.
>
> **Mozilla-only properties and pseudo-classes (avoid using on websites)**
>
> **Note**: These properties and pseudo-classes will only work in Mozilla applications such as Firefox, and are not on a standards
>   track. Some of them apply only to XUL elements.

The general message is not to use the non-standard `-moz` extensions to CSS.
These will gradually be phased out in favor of the current standard.

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helped me to find [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1404367/516482) myself.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DOM Inspector (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) on the page `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` I found a `#navigator-toolbox` that contains all the toolbars.

So, I adapted my `userChrome.css` to:

```
/* For: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
   From: https://superuser.com/questions/1404144/arranging-firefoxs-ui-bars-with-moz-box-ordinal-group/1404367#1404367 */
#navigator-toolbox {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    }
#toolbar-menubar { order: 1; }
#TabsToolbar { order: 4; }
#nav-bar { order: 2; }
#PersonalToolbar { order: 3; }
```

Comment: Please note that such solutions can change without notice, as did happen to you.

Comment: @harrymc I know: "Change is the only constant." :) It happened to me a few times in the past already. Fortunately XUL/DOM offers the possibility to re-change it if it changes. Thanks for reminding me concerning this here.